# How to change the current line color in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pro-power-tools

Maybe it's trivial but I couldn't find an answer to it for several weeks. It's set to some light gray color which is very bothersome in a dark color theme.

Any ideas how I can change this? Or even disable it if there is no way to change it.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
Tools\Options\Productivity Power Tools\Highlight Current Line
```

to enable/disable the feature.

```
Tools\Options\Environment\Fonts and Colors\

Current Line (Extension)
Current Line Inactive (Extension)
```

to change the colors.

Comment: So, just so other people can feel like they're not crazy if they're seeing the same thing, I don't have the Current Line (Extension) option listed. I had to disable the highlight line option altogether.

Comment: the Current Line (Extension) option was listed under Text Editor. so Tools\Options\Environment\Fonts and Colors\Text Editor\Current Line (Extension)

Comment: For VS 2013 the option is Highlight Current Line (Active/Inactive)

Comment: For VS 2019: Tools/Options/Text Editor/General/Highlight current line

Answer (score 13):

If you as many of us use ReSharper, highlighting current line can be achieved via:

> **ReSharper/Options...**; **Environment/Editor** on the left; check "**Highlight
>   current Line**" on the right.

After that you may need to restart Visual studio and if you do not like the color, change it via:

> **Tools/Options...**; **Environment/Fonts and Colors** on the left; "**ReSharper
>   Current Line Highlight**" on the right

See more details in [here](http://sebastianpatten.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/highlight-the-current-line-in-visual-studio-2010-with-resharper/)

Comment: I had to disable VS's standard highlight current line via Tools > Options > Text Editor, in the Display group, uncheck "Highlight current line" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883966/disabling-highlighting-of-current-line-in-the-visual-studio-2012-editor

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Visual Studio Theme Generator](http://frickinsweet.com/tools/Theme.mvc.aspx) , where can you change all colors.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Brian's answer above, to have the extension, you need to install the VC10 extension from extension manager, see those two links below how to do it:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/05/03/visual-studio-2010-extension-manager-and-the-new-vs-2010-powercommands-extension.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/09/visual-studio-2010-productivity-power-tool-extensions.aspx