# Disabling highlighting of current line in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

The Visual Studio editor highlights the current line by changing the background color of the current line.  Is there a simple way to disable this highlighting? Otherwise, which parameter in Fonts and Colors dialog controls the background color of the currently selected line in the editor?

Comment: The Beta version changes how the line highlighting is done—now it's a colored border around the current line—but I still don't like it! Great question; I spent way too long hunting around in the settings window but coming up empty handed.

Comment: Is there a setting for changing the color as well?

Comment: Commentary is the best way for code organization;
in visual studio it fails due to line gaps, cause a forwarded perception for having it with background color set;
result the code visualization broken on better seeing it as a solid logical instructions when looking at the code;

Answer (score 309, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to disable this highlighting?

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor, in the Display group, uncheck "Highlight current line"

> Which parameter in Fonts and Colors dialog controls the background color of the currently selected line in the editor?

The colors are named "Highlight Current Line (Active)" and "Highlight Current Line (Inactive)"

Comment: My problem is that the small border around the "line highlight" obscures the squiggly warnings that R# puts underneath text. I don't suppose we can set the transparency of the border...

Comment: for me with R# 7.1 it works simply setting foreground color of Highlight Current Line (Active) as same as background color (in my case black)

Comment: @Stefano.net wouldn't that make the highlight not visible, which is the same as turning it off?

Comment: The border was driving me nuts too!  To get rid of it change the foreground color to "Automatic".  This means you'll only be able to customise the background colour, but was good enough for me.

Comment: At least on my machine (VS2013), turning off the annoying highlight bar significantly sped up the scrolling speed - or at least changed from snail-speed to only slow.  Changing the color of the bar probably wouldn't do that.

Comment: If you want remove the border, set background and forceground with same color.

Comment: Got here for color names.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2015 its under Tools > Options > Text Editor > General - last option - Highlight Current Line.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, the color settings (Active) and (Inactive) were combined into a single "Highlight Current Line" setting.

Answer (score 34):

To disable the border around the current line

### In VS 2019

Go to : **Environment -> Fonts and Colors:**

Find the display item: **Highlight Current Line**

Set the **item foreground** color to: **Automatic**

### In VS 2017 and earlier

Go to : **Tools -> Options -> Text Editor:**

Find the display items:

- Highlight Current Line (Active)
- Highlight Current Line (Inactive)

Set the **item foreground** color to: **Automatic**

Comment: It's like a great weight has been lifted. The essence of this answer is that the border is controlled by the 'Item foreground" property, which can be used to set the border to any other selectable color as well as disabling it. I've avoided this setting in the past expecting that it would change the text color of the current line (like 'foreground' settings typically do). This is not the case - it only controls the border. I only wish I'd found Sc0tTy's answer years ago.

Answer (score 17):

if its visual code make

```
"editor.renderLineHighlight": "none"
```

Comment: (mac)

command + shift + p -> 'Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)'

Drop the above code within the outermost bracket.

Comment: I couldn't find the 'Tools' or 'environment' mentioned on the above answers. This just worked.

Answer (score 8):

> The Visual Studio editor highlights the current line by changing the **background color** of the current line.

The only time I've seen this is when "Use Windows High Contrast settings" is enabled (Options > Environment > General)

[image]

[image]

With this setting disabled, I just get a subtle grey box to indicate the current line (this may depend on your Color Theme):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Resharper, it's:

**Tools -> Options -> Text Editor:**

```
  ReSharper Current Line Highlight
```

Answer (score 3):

### For VsCode 2021 version users

**Workspace > Text-Editor > Render Line Highlight > none**

Answer (score 2):

**press  ->** Ctrl + comma

**Search =>** Render Line Highlight

select **none** from the options

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer, I'd like to mention that **Visual Assist** (the tomato icon) also have an *highlight current line* feature, that can still be active while your Visual Studio highlight option is turned off.
This drove me crazy! Find it in *Visual Assist Option* panel, *Display* category.

So don't forget to also uncheck the VisualAssist highlight option.

**edit**
my settings:

- Visual Assist option turned **off**
- Visual Studio option turned **on** (in the Text Editors part)
- In the font color settings, for *Highlight current line* (active and inactive), set the *foreground* to *Automatic*
- Finally you can set your highlight color as you want with the *background* color.

Last point, sometimes Visual Studio mess things up even more, you may have to restart it, or close/open your tabs... sadly, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

**Settings** > Type **'render line height'** on search bar > change it to **none**

Answer (score -1):

Visual assist and vsvim extensions were conflicting. So I disabled it within the visual assist options.

Uncheck the option: Highlighting->Highlight results of Quick Find and Find in Files.
For some reason "esc" doesn't work .

Comment: This seems to be not answering this specific question.