# Is there a way to disable those horizontal lines?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Those lines surrounding the line in which the cursor is. I don't know how to search for it in the command palette, and haven't seen an aswer on the internet

Comment: Not exact duplicate as it's for VS not VS code but the 3rd answer has a solution for this. Hope it helps. [Disabling highlighting of current line in the Visual Studio editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883966/disabling-highlighting-of-current-line-in-the-visual-studio-editor)

Comment: @Omkar76 VS is completely different to VSCode

Comment: @HongOoi, I know. I told OP to look at [third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439530/12485639) that provides solution for VSCode.