# How to change the current line color in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288724/how-to-change-the-current-line-color-in-visual-studio-2010) for Visual Studio 2010.
However, the answer does not work anymore with Visual Studio 2013.

How to change the current line color in Visual Studio 2013 ?
I would like to make it more visible.

Comment: Is there not an option under in the Visual Studio Tools, Fonts and Colors section?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

1. Open Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts And Colors.
2. Select 'Text Editor' in 'Show settings for:'
3. In 'Display items', select 'Highlight Current Line (Active)'.
4. Change the color.

Comment: Tools -> Options -> *Environment* -> Fonts and Colors

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, the settings (Active) and (Inactive) were combined into a single "Highlight Current Line" setting.

Comment: If you have Resharper, you need to change "ReSharper Current Line Highlight" too.

Comment: Also, in the Dark theme, don't expect the color that you choose for this will be **exactly** honored.

See this **closed** bug report: [Highlight Current Line](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25081/highlight-current-line-color.html) for an explanation

Comment: in Visual Studio 2019 setting color is useless, until you check
**Tools -> Options -> Text Editor ->General -> Display -> Highlight current line**